# most reliable way to deploy ROR3 website on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, git, capistrano, reliability

I used rvm installed ruby 1.9.2 p136 and rails 3.0.3, for development is easy but deployment I have merely 0 experience.

Passenger3 + apache2?
lighttpd proxy + mongrel?

can anyone describe briefly, what web server, monitoring and tools you used in production server?

Answer (score 1):

I like Passenger and apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Try use magicmonkey: https://github.com/pioz/magicmonkey